# Coefficient of determination (R^2) for a non-linear regression versus a more meaningful measure of error

Tags: nonlinear-regression, measurement-error

I was looking at [Riparian Buffer Width, Vegetative Cover, and Nitrogen Removal Effectiveness: A Review of Current Science and Regulations](http://www.iatp.org/documents/riparian-buffer-width-vegetative-cover-and-nitrogen-removal-effectiveness-a-review-of-curr), when I saw $R^2$ applied to a logarithmic model:

[image]

But reading [Why Is There No R-Squared for Nonlinear Regression?](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/why-is-there-no-r-squared-for-nonlinear-regression), this reasoning as to why $R^2$ can't possibly work, makes sense:

> For linear models, the sums of the squared errors always add up in a specific manner: SS Regression + SS Error = SS Total. [...] In nonlinear regression, SS Regression + SS Error do not equal SS Total!

Unless, there are certain conditions, that perhaps the relatively simple model, $a\log(x) + b$, might satisfy, that make the error calculation behave nice enough for $R^2$ to be meaningful?

If not, is there an analogous measure of error in terms of calculating simplicity? Ideally I would like to be able to demonstrate and teach step-by-step calculations in Excel. However, if not, I have Mathematica available to me. I read about Kendall's Tau and Spearman methods, but I feel I don't have the knowledge to judge validity—what I'm reading about ordinality / ranking makes me feel these measurements are unfit for my data.

Comment: In non-linear regression non-linearity is in the terms of coefficients. Judging from your table all the models are linear in terms of coefficients, hence the quip about $R^2$ does not apply here.

Comment: Also, R-squared is perfectly fine for non-linear regression (people even compute it for deep neural networks!), it's just that the happy coincidences that make R-squared easy to compute for linear regression don't exist elsewhere, so you have to use the general formula. Also, you lose the interpretation of "variance explained", but other than that it's perfectly fine